# Обновляющаяся строка?

Tags: java

Как сделать обновляющуюся строку?
Например есть код

```
for(int x=0;x<100;x++) System.out.println(x);
```

Я не хочу чтобы был вывод в новую строку.

А в одну и ту же. Чтобы 1 в последовательности заменялось 2, и это было в одной строке

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сама Java очищать консоль не умеет. Но есть небольшая библиотечка, позволяющая отправлять управляющие последовательности в любую ANSI-совместимую консоль - [Jansi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi):

```
AnsiConsole.systemInstall();
System.out.print(Ansi.ansi().eraseScreen());
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    try {
        System.out.print(Ansi.ansi().cursor(0, 0).a(x));
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Используй `\r` вместо перевода строки:

```
System.out.print(x + "\r");
```

Comment: если в цикл автора вставлять, тогда уж System.out.print("\r" + i); например, после вывода добавить Thread.sleep(100);

Comment: @DaysLikeThis, обычно непринципиально, в каком они порядке.

Answer (score 0):

Элементарное что можно сделать, каждую итерацию цикла, очищать консоль через обращения к bash, с помощью например того же класса `System`.

Comment: Так всю консоль чистить не просили...

Answer (score 0):

Если в одну строку то:

```
for(int x=0;x<100;x++) System.out.print(x);
```

разница в println и print
Возможно нужно будет добавлять пробелы:

```
for(int x=0;x<100;x++) System.out.print(x+" ");
```

Comment: Я имел ввиду чтобы было не так '1 2'
А чтобы 1 в последовательности заменялось 2, и это было в одной строке